# WSO2: save a property in a sequence A and use it in another sequence B (in the same car)

Tags: wso2

I'm a newbie in WSO2.

I've a sequence A in which I set a property saving my current message ...

```
<property name="InitialMessage" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<log level="full">
    <property name="INITIAL MESSAGE" expression="get-property('InitialMessage')"/>
</log>
```

This is working right ...

I'd like to use InitialMessage in a second sequence B

```
        <log level="custom">
             <property name="INITIAL MESSAGE" expression="get-property('InitialMessage')"/>
        </log>
```

but in my log I've the following

TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-04 13:36:29,155]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  **INITIAL MESSAGE = null** {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}

NOTE 1: the two sequences are in the same composite application project and deployed in the same .car

NOTE 2: My process start with a message processor (sampling) named  OperCupInvokeSimonCipeSamplingInputMessageProcessor that invoke OperCupSimonCipeSenderMessage sequence (where I set my property ...). This sequence use the OperCupSimonCipeFaultManager sequence in case of fault (that is my use case now ...), and where I'd like to use my property value.

There is no proxy-services component: could be this the problem?

Unfortunately I can't put an image for the structure (I don't have enough stackoverflow "reputation" :-) ... ), so I hope that is clear

NOTE 3
Here  you're my first sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
 name="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeSenderManager"
   onError="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeFaultManager">
 <log level="full">
    <property name="where" value="**********
     OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON_CIPE-SENDER-MANAGER - STARTING THE SEQUENCE
     OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON_CIPE-SENDER-MANAGER .... "/>
 </log>
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default"
   type="STRING"/>
<log level="full">
    <property name="where" value="**********
       OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON_CIPE-SENDER-MANAGER - SAVE THE CURRENT MESSAGE ...."/>
</log>
<property name="InitialMessage" expression="$body" scope="default"
     type="STRING"/>
<log level="full">
    <property name="INITIAL MESSAGE"
       expression="get-property('InitialMessage')"/>
</log>
<log level="full">
    <property name="where" value="**********
        OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON_CIPE-SENDER-MANAGER - BEFORE TO CALL AN EXTERNAL SERVICE
     ...."/>
</log>
<header name="Action" scope="default" value=""/>
<property name="SOAPAction" value="" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
<send>
    <endpoint key="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeServiceSimonEndPoint"/>
</send>
```

and this is the second sequence (that is the fault sequence of the first one ..)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    name="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeFaultManager">
  <log level="full">
    <property name="where" value="**********
      OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - STARTING THE SEQUENCE
      OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER .... "/>
    <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
    <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE"
       expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
    <property name="ERROR_DETAIL"
       expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
    <property name="ERROR_EXCEPTION"
       expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
</log>
<log level="custom">
    <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
        xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="retry_count"
        expression="get-property('retry_count')"/>
</log>
<filter xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
       xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
       xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('retry_count')">
    <then>
        <property name="retry_count"
          expression="number(get-property('retry_count'))+1" scope="default"
          type="STRING"/>
        <filter xpath="number(get-property('retry_count')) &gt; 3">
            <then>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="where" value="**********
                       OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - SERVICE SIMON 
                        DOES NOT RESPOND ....
                    "/>
                    <property name="where" value="**********
                 OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - RETRY_COUNT &gt; 3 .... "/>
                    <property name="DROPPING--COUNT"
                     expression="get-property('retry_count')"/>
                </log>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="where" value="**********
            OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - RECOVER INITIAL MESSAGE .... "/>
                    <property name="INITIAL MESSAGE"
                      expression="get-property('InitialMessage')"/>
                </log>
                <store
                  messageStore="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeUnresolvedMessageStore"/>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="where" value="**********
        OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - THE MESSAGE IS IN UNRESOLVED MESSAGE
            STORE .... "/>
                </log>
            </then>
            <else>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="where" value="**********
         OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - SERVICE SIMON DOES NOT RESPOND ....
        "/>
                    <property name="RETRY_COUNT_VALUE"
                      expression="number(get-property('retry_count'))"/>
                    <property name="where" value="**********
       OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - RESTORE AGAIN THE MESSAGE IN WORKING
     MESSAGE STORE .... "/>
                </log>
                <store
                 messageStore="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeWorkingMessageStore"/>
            </else>
        </filter>
    </then>
    <else>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="where" value="**********
       OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - THE FIRST TIME THAT SERVICE SIMON
       DOES NOT RESPOND .... "/>
            <property name="RETRY_COUNT_INITIAL_VALUE"
 expression="get-property('retry_count')"/>
        </log>
        <property name="retry_count" value="1" scope="default"
    type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="where" value="**********
  OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - STORING CURRENT MESSAGE IN WORKING
     MESSAGE STORE FOR THE FIRST TIME .... "/>
            <property name="RETRY_COUNT_INITIAL_VALUE"
       expression="get-property('retry_count')"/>
        </log>
        <log level="custom">
             <property name="where" value="**********
    OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - RECOVER INITIAL MESSAGE .... "/>
        </log>
        <log level="custom">
             <property name="INITIAL MESSAGE"
     expression="get-property('InitialMessage')"/>
        </log>
        <store messageStore="OperCupInvokeSimonCipeWorkingMessageStore"/>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="where" value="**********
      OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - MESSAGE STORED IN WORKING MESSAGE
      STORE FOR THE FIRST TIME .... "/>
        </log>
    </else>
</filter>
```

and this is the log during running ..

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:10,098]  INFO      {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08  /addressing/anonymous, WSAction: process, SOAPAction: process, MessageID: urn:uuid:A1F6F35D103B414B7A273081153832130-1534945985, Direction: request, where = ********** OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON_CIPE-SENDER-MANAGER - SAVE THE CURRENT MESSAGE ...., Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><gen:generaCupXml xmlns:gen="http://generazionecup.interfacecsi.simonadapterwscup.simon.csi.it" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><in0 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:string">

    &lt;RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;&lt;ID_RICHIESTA&gt;61407&lt;/ID_RICHIESTA&gt;&lt;USER&gt;ws.csipiemcol&lt;/USER&gt;&lt;PASSWORD&gt;sE6454&lt;/PASSWORD&gt;&lt;CUP_GENERAZIONE id_progetto="61407"&gt;&lt;DATI_GENERALI_PROGETTO anno_decisione="2013" cumulativo="N" codifica_locale="61407" natura="02" tipologia="12" settore="11" sottosettore="72" categoria="011"/&gt;&lt;LOCALIZZAZIONE stato="5" regione="01" provincia="001" comune="001219"/&gt;&lt;DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;REALIZZ_ACQUISTO_SERVIZI_FORMAZIONE denom_progetto="SERVIZI LAVORO PROV. VC - Op. B3 - Dir.93-2013 - Ob. II.E" denom_ente_corso="ELCAT S.P.A." tipo_ind_area_rifer="01" ind_area_rifer="CSO FRANCIA 98" obiett_corso="PROGETTO NELL'AMBITO DELLA DIRETTIVA Test-C PERCORSI FORMATIVI PER IL LAVORO (RIATTIVO)" mod_intervento_frequenza="ORARIO: non specificato; TOTALE ORE PER PARTECIPANTE: non specificato" strum_progr="99" desc_strum_progr="POR FSE PIEMONTE - 2007IT052PO011"/&gt;&lt;/DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;FINANZIAMENTO costo="1.05" finanziamento="1.05"&gt;&lt;CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;001&lt;/CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;&lt;/FINANZIAMENTO&gt;&lt;/CUP_GENERAZIONE&gt;&lt;/RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;

   </in0></gen:generaCupXml></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} 
  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:10,107]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: process, SOAPAction: process, MessageID: urn:uuid:A1F6F35D103B414B7A273081153832130-1534945985, Direction: request, INITIAL MESSAGE = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><gen:generaCupXml xmlns:gen="http://generazionecup.interfacecsi.simonadapterwscup.simon.csi.it" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><in0 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:string">

    &lt;RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;&lt;ID_RICHIESTA&gt;61407&lt;/ID_RICHIESTA&gt;&lt;USER&gt;ws.csipiemcol&lt;/USER&gt;&lt;PASSWORD&gt;sE6454&lt;/PASSWORD&gt;&lt;CUP_GENERAZIONE id_progetto="61407"&gt;&lt;DATI_GENERALI_PROGETTO anno_decisione="2013" cumulativo="N" codifica_locale="61407" natura="02" tipologia="12" settore="11" sottosettore="72" categoria="011"/&gt;&lt;LOCALIZZAZIONE stato="5" regione="01" provincia="001" comune="001219"/&gt;&lt;DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;REALIZZ_ACQUISTO_SERVIZI_FORMAZIONE denom_progetto="SERVIZI LAVORO PROV. VC - Op. B3 - Dir.93-2013 - Ob. II.E" denom_ente_corso="ELCAT S.P.A." tipo_ind_area_rifer="01" ind_area_rifer="CSO FRANCIA 98" obiett_corso="PROGETTO NELL'AMBITO DELLA DIRETTIVA Test-C PERCORSI FORMATIVI PER IL LAVORO (RIATTIVO)" mod_intervento_frequenza="ORARIO: non specificato; TOTALE ORE PER PARTECIPANTE: non specificato" strum_progr="99" desc_strum_progr="POR FSE PIEMONTE - 2007IT052PO011"/&gt;&lt;/DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;FINANZIAMENTO costo="1.05" finanziamento="1.05"&gt;&lt;CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;001&lt;/CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;&lt;/FINANZIAMENTO&gt;&lt;/CUP_GENERAZIONE&gt;&lt;/RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;

   </in0></gen:generaCupXml></soapenv:Body>, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><gen:generaCupXml xmlns:gen="http://generazionecup.interfacecsi.simonadapterwscup.simon.csi.it" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><in0 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:string">

    &lt;RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;&lt;ID_RICHIESTA&gt;61407&lt;/ID_RICHIESTA&gt;&lt;USER&gt;ws.csipiemcol&lt;/USER&gt;&lt;PASSWORD&gt;sE6454&lt;/PASSWORD&gt;&lt;CUP_GENERAZIONE id_progetto="61407"&gt;&lt;DATI_GENERALI_PROGETTO anno_decisione="2013" cumulativo="N" codifica_locale="61407" natura="02" tipologia="12" settore="11" sottosettore="72" categoria="011"/&gt;&lt;LOCALIZZAZIONE stato="5" regione="01" provincia="001" comune="001219"/&gt;&lt;DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;REALIZZ_ACQUISTO_SERVIZI_FORMAZIONE denom_progetto="SERVIZI LAVORO PROV. VC - Op. B3 - Dir.93-2013 - Ob. II.E" denom_ente_corso="ELCAT S.P.A." tipo_ind_area_rifer="01" ind_area_rifer="CSO FRANCIA 98" obiett_corso="PROGETTO NELL'AMBITO DELLA DIRETTIVA Test-C PERCORSI FORMATIVI PER IL LAVORO (RIATTIVO)" mod_intervento_frequenza="ORARIO: non specificato; TOTALE ORE PER PARTECIPANTE: non specificato" strum_progr="99" desc_strum_progr="POR FSE PIEMONTE - 2007IT052PO011"/&gt;&lt;/DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;FINANZIAMENTO costo="1.05" finanziamento="1.05"&gt;&lt;CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;001&lt;/CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;&lt;/FINANZIAMENTO&gt;&lt;/CUP_GENERAZIONE&gt;&lt;/RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;

   </in0></gen:generaCupXml></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:10,112]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: process, SOAPAction: process, MessageID: urn:uuid:A1F6F35D103B414B7A273081153832130-1534945985, Direction: request, where = ********** OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON_CIPE-SENDER-MANAGER - BEFORE TO CALL AN EXTERNAL SERVICE ...., Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><gen:generaCupXml xmlns:gen="http://generazionecup.interfacecsi.simonadapterwscup.simon.csi.it" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><in0 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:string">

    &lt;RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;&lt;ID_RICHIESTA&gt;61407&lt;/ID_RICHIESTA&gt;&lt;USER&gt;ws.csipiemcol&lt;/USER&gt;&lt;PASSWORD&gt;sE6454&lt;/PASSWORD&gt;&lt;CUP_GENERAZIONE id_progetto="61407"&gt;&lt;DATI_GENERALI_PROGETTO anno_decisione="2013" cumulativo="N" codifica_locale="61407" natura="02" tipologia="12" settore="11" sottosettore="72" categoria="011"/&gt;&lt;LOCALIZZAZIONE stato="5" regione="01" provincia="001" comune="001219"/&gt;&lt;DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;REALIZZ_ACQUISTO_SERVIZI_FORMAZIONE denom_progetto="SERVIZI LAVORO PROV. VC - Op. B3 - Dir.93-2013 - Ob. II.E" denom_ente_corso="ELCAT S.P.A." tipo_ind_area_rifer="01" ind_area_rifer="CSO FRANCIA 98" obiett_corso="PROGETTO NELL'AMBITO DELLA DIRETTIVA Test-C PERCORSI FORMATIVI PER IL LAVORO (RIATTIVO)" mod_intervento_frequenza="ORARIO: non specificato; TOTALE ORE PER PARTECIPANTE: non specificato" strum_progr="99" desc_strum_progr="POR FSE PIEMONTE - 2007IT052PO011"/&gt;&lt;/DESCRIZIONE&gt;&lt;FINANZIAMENTO costo="1.05" finanziamento="1.05"&gt;&lt;CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;001&lt;/CODICE_TIPOLOGIA_COP_FINANZ&gt;&lt;/FINANZIAMENTO&gt;&lt;/CUP_GENERAZIONE&gt;&lt;/RICHIESTA_GENERAZIONE_CUP&gt;

   </in0></gen:generaCupXml></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:10,842]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: , WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:34abd0a3-45a1-45ef-8026-d738d60e702b, Direction: response, where = ********** OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - STARTING THE SEQUENCE OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER .... , ERROR_CODE = null, ERROR_MESSAGE = null, ERROR_DETAIL = null, ERROR_EXCEPTION = null, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><soapenv:Code><soapenv:Value>soapenv:Server.userException</soapenv:Value></soapenv:Code><soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">it.csi.simon.simonadapterwscup.exception.generazionecup.GenerazioneCupException:Errore durante la generazione cup.Porta di Dominio del soggetto SPCMinisteroEconomiaFinanzeCollaudo non disponibile (nested: org.apache.axis.AxisFault, Porta di Dominio del soggetto SPCMinisteroEconomiaFinanzeCollaudo non disponibile)</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">tst-jboss8.csi.it</ns1:hostname></soapenv:Detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
   TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:10,929]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  retry_count = null {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
   TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:11,074]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  where = ********** OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - THE FIRST TIME THAT SERVICE SIMON DOES NOT RESPOND .... , RETRY_COUNT_INITIAL_VALUE = null {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
   TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:11,075]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  where = ********** OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - STORING CURRENT MESSAGE IN WORKING MESSAGE STORE FOR THE FIRST TIME .... , RETRY_COUNT_INITIAL_VALUE = 1 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
   TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:11,076]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  where = ********** OPER-CUP-INVOKE-SIMON-CIPE-FAULT-MANAGER - RECOVER INITIAL MESSAGE ....  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
   TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-08 11:12:11,163]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  INITIAL MESSAGE = null {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

As you can see at the beginning the message is saved in  the property end then, when I'm in the fault sequence, my variable is null

Answer (score 1):

This must work, if you configure  sequenceB after the sequenceA.  Basically in ESB, Once you set a property in to the message path, It can be retrieve any point of the message path (even from out sequence as well). I hope you are developing a proxy service ?  then please make sure to configure seqB after seqA in your in-sequence or out-sequence.

Comment: Hi Asela! I've integrated my question with some more info (see NOTE 2). SeqB is the fault sequence of SeqA. Can I manage the sequence order in some way? Thanks!

Comment: @Cesare The order between sequences are based on how they are called. Actually there is no order between a sequence and its fault sequence. The fault sequence is invoked when there is fault occurred in the respective sequence. So in this case most probably fault has occurred before the property has been set to the context. So when you try to print the property in fault sequence there won't be any value for it. How you invoke your sequence in your case.

Comment: @Ravagan: thank you for te reply. I've added a new note (NOTE3) in my question giving you the details of my sequence and of the logs for errors. Any suggestion?